# Hyper-V: virtual 32 bit OS on 64bit OS

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

Is it possible to run 32-bit virtual OS(Windows Server 2003) on 64-bit machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Standard isnstalled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Of course.